# How to use the "window" property in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement this "Scroll back to top" button found here:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp

---

I'm new to Angular and my attempts to implement this keep getting me errors and type errors.

This is my code:

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="country-card-container">
   <button (click)="topFunction()" class="scroll-top">TOP</button>
   <app-country-card *ngFor="let country of displayCountries" [country]="country" class="country-cards"></app-country-card>
</div>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.sass']
})
export class HomeComponent {

    mybutton = document.getElementsByClassName("scroll-top");
    
    // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
    window.onscroll = this.scrollFunction();
    
    scrollFunction() {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        this.mybutton.style.display = "block";
     } else {
        this.mybutton.style.display = "none";
     }
    }
    
    // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
    topFunction() {
      document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
     document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
    }
}
```

---

I'm getting the errors:

```
Unexpected keyword or identifier.ts(1434)

Member 'window' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7008)

Cannot find name 'scrollFunction'.ts(2304)

Property 'style' does not exist on type 'HTMLCollectionOf<Element>'.ts(2339)
```

---

I also tried putting

```
window.onscroll = this.scrollFunction();
```

in ngOnInit like this:

```
ngOnInit(){

    window.onscroll = this.scrollFunction();
}
```

but that doesn't work either.

---

How do I implement this? What did I do wrong and how do you fix it?

Comment: First of all you shouldn't use `document.getElementsByClassName()` in Angular. You can see how to create buttons in Angular here: https://angular.io/guide/event-binding

Comment: `window.onscroll = this.scrollFunction();` doesn't make much sense. `this.scrollFunction()` doesn't explicitly return anything. `window.onscroll` is set to `undefined`. You can't set properties like this `window.onscroll = this.scrollFunction();` in a class definition outside a function.

Comment: So I just can't use the method given in the W3 School link? It can't be implemented in Angular and I need to find another way? Is that what you guys are saying?

Comment: No, that's not what we're saying. You can do it that way, but you shouldn't do it that way in Angular. You have errors in your code that have to be fixed. Fix them and declare `window`.

Comment: I recommend to do the scroll in angularway, otherwise your code will be a mashup of angular and javascript: https://angular.io/api/common/ViewportScroller and https://dev.to/ferfox1981/tree-ways-to-scroll-to-an-element-using-angular-1dlj

Comment: @akkonrad THANKS! In your second link though the guy says, "I read some sources that says Angular Material blocks scrolling, but I'm not sure."....is that true? Because I'm using Angular Material. Do you know if this [https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api) is what I'm looking for? Could I do a scroll to top with it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the problem is that you try to declare a window property of your component by doing this:

```
export class HomeComponent {
  // this code is not valid, because you try to declare a class property here, not to get the window reference
  window.onscroll = this.scrollFunction();
}
```

Angular has a directive made specially for those purposes, called `@HostListener`. I would recommend you to consider it.

```
@Component({...})
export class HomeComponent {
  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll(event: Event) {
    // do whatever you want here, including manipulations with the window object as it's available here
    console.log(window);
  }
}
```

Here is a reference to the official docs: https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener

Good luck :)